# Reliable way to do an ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the most reliable way to do the ACTION_IMAGE_CATPURE intent on Android? I've tried multiple things I've found online, and none of them work on every device. My test devices are a Nexus 6 (Android 6.0.1) and a Lenovo phone (4.4.2).

I've tried the following (removed redundant code like permissions - these are clearly working properly):

**Option A (only works on Nexus 6)**

```
final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
root.mkdirs();
final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(root, fname));

Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

try {
     startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, 1);
} catch (SecurityException e) { }

// ....

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println(new File(outputFileUri.toString()).exists()));
    // This prints false on Kitkat, but true on 6.0
```

**Option B (doesn't work on either, but seems that it should work on both)**

```
Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
outputFileUri = takePhotoIntent.getData();
// start intent

// .....

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.out.println(new File(outputFileUri.toString()).exists()));
    // This prints false on everything
```

It seems like there **should** be a reliable way to do this across Android versions, but I've been on stack overflow for the past hour and there are 10+ solutions I've tried, and none of them work on the older version of Android.

**How do I reliably get the Uri from the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?**

Comment: show your logcat whats system is saying?

Comment: The log is full of randomness - what should I be looking for? There are no errors thrown prior to the print statement. I mean, I could copy/paste it, but it's going to be about 500 lines without knowing what to look for.

Comment: @SohailZahid if you meant the System.out above, it just prints false as described.

Comment: you have sort into logs and see whats possible issues without that we can make only guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // This prints false on Kitkat, but true on 6.0

That should fail on all versions of Android. `outputFileUri.toString()` will be something like `"file:///..."` (for some value of `...`), and that is not a valid filesystem path. Perhaps Google updated `File` to handle stripping off the scheme.

The better solution is to hold onto `new File(root, fname)`, which is the correct `File` object. Bear in mind that your process may be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground, so hold onto this in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Also bear in mind that your approach will not work on API Level 24+, once your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, as [`file` `Uri` values are banned](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

> but seems that it should work on both

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) does not state that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` will return *anything*, let alone the `Uri`. I agree that this is what logically should be the answer, but there are lots of things in Android that defy logic.

> It seems like there should be a reliable way to do this across Android versions

Well, expecting reliable results out of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is silly. You are delegating to a third-party app. There are thousands of Android device models, and those ship with hundreds of camera apps. There are hundreds more on the Play Store and elsewhere. Many camera app developers do not test `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` very well, and there are many camera apps that have bugs, such as ignoring `EXTRA_OUTPUT` entirely.

Many more will get tripped up by the aforementioned `file` `Uri` ban, as they may not be expecting a `content` `Uri` here. Heck, *Google* does not even bother testing `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` *on their own camera app* all that much, to the extent that they do not handle `content` `Uri` values, and [will not do so for some time](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211163).

Feel free to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, but just be prepared to fail gracefully.

Comment: Ok, so if I shouldn't use ACTION_IMAGE_CATURE, how *should* I take a photo? Do I have to make my own camera app?

Comment: @CaptainForge: Your options are: use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and live with third-party camera app bugs, use a library (e.g., [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2)) and live with *its* bugs, or use the camera APIs directly.